# Generate an independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) random gaussian matrix

Tags: python, random, gaussian

What is the best/accurate way to create an i.i.d. random Gaussian matrix using Python?

What is pseudo-random? And would that suffice?

Comment: What are you planning on using it for?

Comment: To initialize random matrix to use in power iteration method for finding eigenvectors. I was wondering if np.random.rand() would be enough.  I need the columns of S to be orthonormal and not perpendicular to some vector

Comment: pseudo-random should be fine then.